# Visibility on UserControl not triggered

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have a page that can contain 4 different user controls, but only one of them should be visible at a time. I would like to do something like this:

```
    <regControls:MyUserControl1 Visibility="{Binding Ctrl1, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}" />
    <regControls:MyUserControl2 Visibility="{Binding Ctrl2, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}" />
    <regControls:MyUserControl3 Visibility="{Binding Ctrl3, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}" />
    <regControls:MyUserControl4 Visibility="{Binding Ctrl4, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}" />
```

But when the component is initialised the converter isn't triggered at all. Even though I bind the property and raise execute change.

I would prefer not to initialise the different controls in the code behind. I'm using WP8 Silverlight (NOT WP 8.1). What am I missing?

EDIT:

I'm beginning to understand the problem. But I don't know how to solve it. We're using GWT so I get a call from GWT layer that tells me what to show:

```
public void ShowMyUserControl1()
{
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyPageViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyUserControl1ViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyUserControl2ViewModel>();             
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyUserControl3ViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MyUserControl4ViewModel>();

  navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(MyPageViewModel).FullName);

   var viewModel = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MyPageViewModel>();
   viewModel.DisplayMyUserControl1();
}

public void ShowMyUserControl2()
{
    ....
}
```

The problem here is that the view model is called and properties triggered before the components are initialised. The problem here is also that I don't know which method is called from GWT. It could be ShowMyUserControl1 or ShowMyUserControl2 (or method requesting control 3 or 4 to be shown. So somehow I need to tell this and at the same time pass parameters to the correct view model with arguments coming from GWT. Messenger (MVVMLight) doesn't work here. Because the message is sent before any control has been initialised and registered to listen to these messages. The user can have left the app and turn off the phone and then come back again, so I need to expect that the view models doesn't exist and needs to be registered.

Answer (score 0):

Is DataContext (ViewModel) support INotifyPropertyChange? 
Any binding errors in console output in VS?
Create breakpoint on property. Does it hint?

Comment: Yes, I have no other problems with other views. Don't know how to trace binding errors for windows phone 8.0. Yes, it breaks on property, when setting it.

Comment: Create new converter and replace one of them. And create breakpoint in. Check inputparams on propertyChange. And show viewModel code.

Comment: See my updated question. New converter does not change anything. Using mvvmlights property change, i.e. RaisePropertyChange(() => "PropertyName")